# Change the color of the image present in the window title bar

Tags: wpf

Have a image besides the 3 (minimize, maximize, close) buttons. the image is not visible clearly when the window background color is set to black. I want to change the color like those 3 buttons change (white when background is black and viceversa), any help is appreciated. Tried canvas with brush, dint help.

setting the image as follows:

```
 var img= new Image()
            {
                Width = 24,
                Height = 24,
                Source =
                    new BitmapImage(
                        new Uri(some.png",
                            UriKind.Absolute)),
                Tag = tag
            };
            stackPanel.Children.Insert(0, img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you want.  Draw a rectangle while using the image as an opacity mask.

```
        <Rectangle x:Name="Icon1" Height="30" Width="30" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IconColorConverter}}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/globe.png"  Stretch="None"  TileMode="Tile" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
```

Use a converter to determine whether the image will be white or black

```
public class IconColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color wb = SystemColors.ActiveBorderColor;
        double gs = (wb.R * 0.3 + wb.G * 0.6 + wb.B * 0.1) / 255.0;
        if (gs > 0.5)
            return Brushes.Black;
        else
            return Brushes.White; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Resources definition:

```
    <local:IconColorConverter x:Key="IconColorConverter"/>
```

So here the image will appear as a white if the active border color is dark and black if the active border color is light and the rest of the rectangle will be transparent.

Comment: Thanks AQuirky, while this works fine with red color, but I was looking at dynamic coloring like how the buttons (min,max,close) works. want to have black<->white color and not other solid colors.

Comment: Fine.  I updated my answer to color the icon white or black depending on the color of the active window border.